# iphone app replace or update?

Tags: iphone, ios

There is an existing iphone app, but its boring.
However the same app shall be replaced by another more exiting app, BUT all data stored in each clients app database has to remain.

Is there a way to write an entirely new app (considering the condition above) or do I have to update the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming, by replacing, you mean a whole different codebase.

As long as your Bundle ID for the old boring app and the new exciting app are the same it doesn't matter. The new app is considered as an update.

If you release the same old boring app with a different Bundle ID, then its considered as a new app, and not as an update.

So, if you want to make use of the old boring app's data, you have to make sure the BundleID remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can just update the app, all data in the document directy of the sandbox is not touched when updating and app.

If you write an new app, then there is no way to get to the data of the old app unless you can grab them from, for example a server.

If you used CoreData, be sure to copy the original CoreData model to the new app.

Comment: ok thx, what about writing a new app and deploy it under the same app id to app store? pretending "its an update" ?

Comment: There should ben no problem there, as long as the bundle identifier is the same it will count as an update.